# Remove file extension from fetched echo (PHP)(HTML)

Tags: php, button, bootstrap-4, echo

```
                  <?php
$files2 = scandir("signatureforms/");
foreach($files2 as $num => $file) {
if($num < 2) { continue ;}
                  ?>
                  <button class="signatureformbutton" value="signatureforms/<?php echo $file;?>">
                         <?php echo $file; ?>          <-------'name'
                  </button>
<?php                             } 
?>
```

So I'm making a button out of every file in the 'signatureforms' folder, but the extensions are all on there. Gotta get those off. Where even in this code would I add something? In the -name- part of the button ("< ?php echo $file; ? >"), right?

-EDIT-
New code thks to commentor:

```
<?php
$files2 = scandir("signatureforms/");
foreach($files2 as $num => $file) {
$ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if($num < 2) { continue ;}
?>
<button class="signatureformbutton" value="signatureforms/<?php echo $file;?>"><?php echo str_replace ( $ext , "", $file ); ?></button>
<?php
}?>
```

working on getting rid of that '.'

-EDIT 2-

Just use $filename = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME); and then echo $filename. sigh.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be getting the extension via 
`$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`
and then replacing it with '' as empty string like

```
str_replace ( $ext , "", $file );
```

and yes, you're right, best place is while adding the data to your buttons

in addition to other answer, chop method is more performant but str_replace should be practicable too

thanks for the comments, since php 5.2 there is an option for exactly that purpose

`$fileWithoutExt= pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME );`

Comment: hey, you're right! Leaves a '.' on there still though. Updated Q

Comment: then concat the extensino with an "." to get rid of it ;)

Comment: so apparently there is a PATHINFO_FILENAME that does all this for us. (●__●)

Comment: nice, didn't had a deeper look at the parameters, will edit my anwser as well

Answer (score 0):

Big dumb

"< ?php echo $file; ? >"

becomes

"< ?php echo chop($file,".jpg"); ? >"

didn't know chop was a thing :/

Comment: your answer takes just care of jpg and is non generic. if OP has multiple filetypes this is not accurate enough